# What is the purpose of ccall and cwarp functions in Emscripten?

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly, emscripten

I'm following the instructions from the Emscripten documentation [here](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-call-function-pointers-from-c), and I want to practice with minimal examples. My final goal is to create a C++ library, compile it to a single wasm binary file and then use these compiled methods in pure-frontend web application.

I do not understand what is the purpose of calling C++ methods with "ccall" when you can just instatiate them directly from "Module". For example, I can use `Module._doubleNumber(9);`, which is shorter than `Module.ccall('doubleNumber','number', ['number'], [9]);`.

Whats the difference between calling one or another?

Here is the complete code:

```c
extern "C" {
    int doubleNumber( int x ) {
        int res = 2*x;
        return res;
    }
}
```

Compiled with

```sh
emcc main.cpp -o main.js -sEXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=_doubleNumber -sEXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=ccall
```

I'm using a simple html document to test results:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WASM Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Module.ccall('doubleNumber','number', ['number'], [9]); // 18
        Module._doubleNumber(9); // 18
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in such the tiny example. There might be issues in big projects.

1. Less important. `Module.ccall` can perform async call with the parameter `async=true`, whereas call to the exported function `Module._doubleNumber` is always sync.
2. More important. At higher optimisation levels (-O2 and above), the closure compiler runs and minifies (changes) function names. A minified name for `_doubleNumber` will be changed to another name, usually unpredictable one, and `Module._doubleNumber` will be undefined.
3. `-sEXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=_doubleNumber` prevents name minifying and can be used for small C libraries. A big C library would require a ton of items listed in `EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS`, and you shall take into account the limited command line length.